# SSH vs Apache port 443

Tags: ssh, debian, apache-http-server, port, sshd

I want move SSH to port 443, but is used by https. In /etc/apache2/ports.conf I commented the lines for listen by this port. In the default site available also commented the lines. For finish, I complete stop apache service, but yet I receive this:

```
$ sudo lsof -i :443
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    32156 root    3u  IPv4 2415725      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
sshd    32156 root    4u  IPv6 2415727      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
```

I don't understand why https continue there if Apache is down?

note: Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3   /  Apache/2.2.22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that output it looks like ssh is listening on port 443. Under where it `COMMAND` is the application or service that is running. Under `NAME` you have `*:https` That says sshd is listening on all interfaces on port https (443)

I think what might be confusing is the name of the port protocol verses the actual port number that is showing up.

My sshd is still on port 22 and I see

`sudo lsof -i :22
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd      976 root    3u  IPv4     9173      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd      976 root    4u  IPv6     9175      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)`

Where as for apache you can see that the command is different

`sudo lsof -i :80
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2  6131     root    4u  IPv6  60547      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 26677 www-data    4u  IPv6  60547      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)`

Comment: `lsof -i :80 -P` will display port numbers instead of names.

Comment: mm thank you! Let 'use you' for a question ;) So, why ssh server -p 443 don't answer? what more I must review?

Comment: There could be a few things.  Firewall `sudo iptables -L`, you might need to restart sshd, check `netstat -an |grep LISTEN` to make sure that the port is being used and listened on. Check your logs for sshd and see if it is throwing an error.

Comment: I forgot comment it, just for the records: I'm not sure why, but after restart the server everything was ok. Before I just was restarting the services.

Answer (score 0):

There's a list at `/etc/services` used to convert port numbers to protocol names to increase readability. The first column clearly says that there's sshd, not apache.

Comment: That's just the **default** ports for each service. OP wanted to move ssh (default:22/tcp) to 443/tcp (used by default by https)